# Check if a time range is between another time range and how many hours Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a start_time and end_time. Which is maximum 24 hours. 
I guess I firstly need to check if this timerange is within another timerange say 21:00-01:00. If it is I need to know how many of the hours is within the timerange. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use ((two- one) / 3600).round

for example

```
one=Time.now #=>2019-01-23 21:19:19 +0530
two=Time.now + 1*60*60 #=>2019-01-23 22:19:27 +0530
((two- one) / 3600).round #=>1
```

difference is 1 hour for two different Time instance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the four arguments of the method below are strings of the form "HH:MM" or "HH:MM:SS". I have provided a pure-Ruby solution that makes string comparisons only (for example: `"17:26" < "18:00" #=> true`). That is, I do not convert the strings to `Time` objects.

```
def time_within_ref?(time_start, time_end, ref_start, ref_end)
  (time_start >= ref_start) &&
  (adj_hour(time_start, time_end) <= adj_hour(ref_start, ref_end))
end

def adj_hour(start_str, end_str)
  end_str[0,2] = (end_str[0,2].to_i + 24).to_s if end_str < start_str
  end_str
end
```

Here are a few examples.

```
time_within_ref?("19:00", "02:00", "18:00", "03:00")
  #=> true 
time_within_ref?("19:00", "04:00", "18:00", "03:00")
  #=> false
time_within_ref?("17:00", "02:00", "18:00", "03:00")
  #=> false
time_within_ref?("18:00", "02:00", "18:00", "03:00")
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "within"? Do you mean that you want to test if there's any overlap between the ranges, or if the first range is fully contained within another?

You can use Time objects in ranges and exploit `#cover?` to check for overlap

```
start_time = 5.hours.ago
end_time = 4.hours.ago

check_range_start = (4.5).hours.ago
check_range_end = (3.5).hours.ago
check_range = (check_range_start..check_range_end)

check_range.cover?(end_time)   # => true
check_range.cover?(start_time) # =>false
```

If both ends of the range is covered by your check range, then your range is fully covered. If only one end is covered, then you have overlap. If neither end is covered, then the ranges do not intersect.

Once you know if there's intersection, then you can trivially compute the distance from one end of the time range to one end of your check range; if you want to know how much time between your check range start and your input start time, simply subtract `start_time - check_range_start`.

Comment: So a bit more background: I need to pass in a start_time and end_time for a job shift. Which can be maximum of 24 hours. Then I want to check if those two fall into a predestined timerange of say 20:00 and 01:00. 
So if a shift is 12:00-19:00 its false. 
And 12:00-21:00 = true 
Or 21:00-03:00 = true

Comment: So far I have this: But doesn´t seem to work. 
`start_time.strftime("%H:%M") >= '20:00'.to_time && '01:00'.to_time <= end_time.strftime("%H:%M")`

Comment: strftime turns a Time object into a string. Make sure you're comparing Time to Time, not Time to String.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to perform this in the database which are far more performant than loading a bunch of records into Rails.

While "pure ruby" solutions are a quick fix they will exhaust the available memory and crash your server given a non-trivial amount of records.

You can use a range together with `.where` to create a `WHERE start_time BETWEEN a AND b` clause that ensures that a time is within A and B.

```
starts_today = Model.where(
  start_time: Time.current.beginning_of_day..Time.current.end_of_day
)
```

If you want to ensure that the entire span between `start_time` and `end_time` is within a set of bounds you can write you own where clause:

```
Model.where(
  "start_time > :a AND end_time < :b", 
  a: Time.current.beginning_of_day, 
  b: Time.current.end_of_day
)
```

> I need to know how many of the hours is within the timerange.

You can do this with the time/date functions in your database. 
On postgres for example you can do:

```
bounds = Time.current.beginning_of_day..Time.current.end_of_day
Model.select(
  "models.*,  (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - start_time ) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - '#{ bounds.end.iso8601 }')) AS number_of_hours"
)
```

Again calculating this in the DB is vital if you for example want to use this in a WHERE clause.

Comment: So a bit more background: I need to pass in a start_time and end_time for a job shift. Which can be maximum of 24 hours. Then I want to check if those two fall into a predestined timerange of say 20:00 and 01:00. 
So if a shift is 12:00-19:00 its false. 
And 12:00-21:00 = true 
Or 21:00-03:00 = true

Comment: So far I have this: But doesn´t seem to work. 
`start_time.strftime("%H:%M") >= '20:00'.to_time && '01:00'.to_time <= end_time.strftime("%H:%M")`

Comment: You can do something like `WHERE a BETWEEN start_time AND end_time AND b BETWEEN start_time AND end_time`.

Comment: In ActiveRecord you could write the query as `Model.where(':a BETWEEN start_time AND end_time AND :b BETWEEN start_time AND end_time', a: predestined_range.start, b: predestined_range.end)`

Comment: So it is in the model I´m doing this. I´m creating a job Shift where start_time is x and end_time is x. 
If this falls within the predestined timerange between 20:00-01:00 I would like to for example add an amount to something. So basically like: 
`if start_time.strftime("%H:%M") >= '20:00'.to_time && '01:00'.to_time <= end_time.strftime("%H:%M")  
 
else  
 
Do something  
end`

Comment: Sorry maybe easier to read: 
`if Shift.start_time.strftime("%H:%M") >= '20:00'.to_time && '01:00'.to_time <= Shift.end_time.strftime("%H:%M")  Do something  else  Do something  end`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. 
`Shift.start_time.strftime("%H:%M") => '20:00' && Shift.end_time.strftime("%H:%M") <= '01:00'`
The .to_time was messing with me and also the ordering.